# updateMatrix x amount of times

Tags: python, matrix

I'm looking for a way to iterate over a function x amount of times depending on user input.

I thought about prompting the user for a number of iterations for the specific function I am updating and then printing (I am calling it in my Main), and storing that number inside of a variable.

Now I am look for a way to implement a {while} loop so that the function iterates until it reaches the number stored inside the first variable.

So the basic idea looks like this:

```
def main():

  mat = input("What file to read")
  count = input("How many iterations?")
  updateMatrix()

...

def updateMatrix(mat):
  while countmat < count
    ...
      ...
        ...
          countmat = countmat += 1
      print()
main()
```

Is this viable?

Comment: Do you know about `for` loops?

Comment: Can't you determine whether it's viable... by trying it?

Comment: I do know about for loops, DSM.

jez - I tried it with this structure, however it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand your question. I will update/delete it if so. Anyway I will try to answer/clarify this.

```
def main():
  mat = input("What file to read")
  count = input("How many iterations?")
  # you should pass your variables in function to use there
  updateMatrix(mat, count) 


def updateMatrix(mat, count):
    # here you can use mat and count variable as you want
    for in in range(count):
        #this loop will be iterated count times
        # if you want to deal with mat, do it
        print()

main()
```